# Using "runghc" in Snap and not throw a webhandler exception. Using tryIO still gives an error

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I am trying to use runGHC inside of snap to filter out only code that can be compiled. However, I am using tryIO but still my webhandler throws an exception when there is a compile error instead of just returning an empty String.

```
import           Exception (tryIO)

...

runOnFileName :: String -> IO (String)
runOnFileName inp = do
   res <- sanitizeSource inp
   case res of
       Just (code, _, _, _)    -> return $ ppr code
       Nothing                 -> return ""

sanitizeSourceString :: String -> String -> IO (String)
sanitizeSourceString fn contents = do
  tmpdir <- getTemporaryDirectory
  let tmp = tmpdir </> fn ++ ".hs"
  exists <- doesFileExist tmp
  unless exists $ writeFile tmp $ contents
  runOnFileName tmp


sanitizeSource :: String -> IO (Maybe RenamedSource)
sanitizeSource inp =  do 
      runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
        dflags <- getSessionDynFlags
        let dflags' = foldl xopt_set dflags
                            [Opt_Cpp, Opt_ImplicitPrelude, Opt_MagicHash]
        setSessionDynFlags dflags
        target <- guessTarget inp Nothing
        setTargets [target]
        load LoadAllTargets
        modSum <- getModSummary $ mkModuleName "Main"
        p <- parseModule modSum
        t <- typecheckModule p
        d <- desugarModule t
        return $ renamedSource d



... in my handler...
eitherSan <- liftIO $ tryIO $ sanitizeSourceString (T.unpack uuid) (fromMaybe "" content)
let sanitized = case eitherSan of
    Left _ -> ""
    Right r -> r
```

However, if I pass "content" that does not compile, my handler fails with a

```
 A web handler threw an exception. Details Parse error: naked expression at top level
```

or whatever the compiler error is. I thought `tryIO` was supposed to catch the exception.

Comment: In Exception I updated the code.

Comment: In what package is the `Exception` module? [hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo) doesn't find a `tryIO` in a module of approximately that name.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Fischer's question about which `tryIO` you're using is the key. That said, either the `tryIO` is only catching IO exceptions or the like, in which case you should use a combinator from `Control.Exception`, or `tryIO` catches polymorphic exceptions, but you haven't specified which you're catching so it defaults to something stupid (like unit) and you need to be more explicit, or, somehow, an exception isn't being thrown but there's just an error value hiding in the thunk returned by sanitizeString, which needs to be forced (by calling `evaluate`) inside the `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch `SourceError`, `GhcApiError`, and `SomeException` using `gcatch`. Here is a stand-alone version of your code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Monad
import GHC
import GHC.Paths ( libdir )
import DynFlags
import Outputable
import System.FilePath
import System.Directory

import Control.Exception (SomeException)
import HscTypes (SourceError, GhcApiError)

runOnFileName :: String -> IO (String)
runOnFileName inp = do
   res <- sanitizeSource inp
   case res of
       Just (code, _, _, _)    -> return $ showSDoc tracingDynFlags (ppr code)
       Nothing                 -> return ""

sanitizeSourceString :: String -> String -> IO (String)
sanitizeSourceString fn contents = do
  tmpdir <- getTemporaryDirectory
  let tmp = tmpdir </> fn ++ ".hs"
  exists <- doesFileExist tmp
  unless exists $ writeFile tmp $ contents
  runOnFileName tmp

sanitizeSource :: String -> IO (Maybe RenamedSource)
sanitizeSource inp = (sanitizeSource' inp)
   `gcatch` (\(e  :: SourceError)   -> return Nothing)
   `gcatch` (\(g  :: GhcApiError)   -> return Nothing)
   `gcatch` (\(se :: SomeException) -> return Nothing)

sanitizeSource' :: String -> IO (Maybe RenamedSource)
sanitizeSource' inp =  do
      runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
        dflags <- getSessionDynFlags
        let dflags' = foldl xopt_set dflags
                            [Opt_Cpp, Opt_ImplicitPrelude, Opt_MagicHash]
        setSessionDynFlags dflags
        target <- guessTarget inp Nothing
        setTargets [target]
        load LoadAllTargets
        modSum <- getModSummary $ mkModuleName "Main"
        p <- parseModule modSum
        t <- typecheckModule p
        d <- desugarModule t
        return $ renamedSource d

eg1 = "module Main where\n\nf x = x + 1\n\nmain = undefined\n" -- will compile
eg2 = "module Main where\n\nf = x + 1\n\nmain = undefined\n"   -- won't compile
```

Example session:

```
*Main> :!rm -v /tmp/*hs
```

Code that parses ok:

```
*Main> r1 <- sanitizeSourceString "fn_eg1" eg1
*Main> r1
"Main.f x = x GHC.Num.+ 1\nMain.main = GHC.Err.undefined"
```

Now, code that does not parse. An error is printed but `r2` does get the empty string,
so the exceptions were caught correctly:

```
*Main> r2 <- sanitizeSourceString "fn_eg2" eg2

/tmp/fn_eg2.hs:3:5: Not in scope: `x'
*Main> r2
""
```